# How to check in only current project?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I have two VS2013 sessions opened, each with a solution that is version controlled by the same visualstudio.com TFS repository.

In one project I wanted to check in some files, but Check In will always want to check in changed files from all my other VS projects.

Is there a way to make Check In work only on the current project?

It's very confusing when checking in project A also checks in project B when I am not ready or certain about the state of project B.

Comment: Which edition of Visual Studio are you using? See "[Suspend and resume your work from the My Work page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181403.aspx#my_work)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check ins are based on your workspace, not the solution or project you are working on, which means a check in will always detect changes made in any of the folders that have been mapped from source control, regardless of which instance of Visual Studio they were made in (since it looks at the physical disk to determine what changed).

You can be more specific about your workspace mappings and/or use multiple workspaces if you wish to have a smaller scope for your check ins, though this brings with it usability complexity as you now need to ensure source control explorer and pending changes are referring to the correct workspace.

Answer (score 2):

If instead of checking in with no scope (defaults to workspace wide) you can right click on the scope you want.

If you right click on the solution and select check in, Visual Studio will filter the checkin for you. It will be scoped to only files in that solution.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more?  Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Whenever this happens to me, if I have made changes in the VS instance i do not want to check in, then navigate back to the one i want to check in, I am presented with an alert box that says something like "the files have changed, would you like to update them?" If this is true for you, you could just say no.

Alternatively, if the each VS instance is touching code in different branches, then you may choose to "exclude" (in team explorer) these other-branchly files.